# how to change the voice in twilio rest api?

Tags: ruby, twilio

I am trying to create a sample app with twilio wherein a call is made. I am generating the twiml through the twiml-ruby gem. I just want to know how to change the voice to woman in this.

default now is man when i use

```
r.Say "hello world"
```

how to pass that voice parameter?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby#getting-started-with-twiml

The documentation specifies a voice parameter:

```
r.Say 'hello there', :voice => 'woman'
```

Comment: is there a way to set this to default for all r.Say?

Comment: I don't know, but you can do someting like this: `def say(msg) r.Say(msg, voice: 'woman') end`